# How to add script to head tag in MkDocs?

Tags: javascript, markdown, mkdocs

I am new to MkDocs and I built up a website using MkDocs and I want to add some script into `<head>...</head>`.

I tried this code at top of my markdown file but it didn't work :

```
<head>
<script>
...
</script>
</head>
```

I found the script would show in `<body>...</body>` rather than in `<head>...</head>`.

How to place `<script>` in `<head>` tag?

Comment: Please share at least minimal code

Answer (score 2):

You can use material. in your theme (mkdocs.yml), add a reference to custom dir, and in that dir, you can add a file named main.html which will be included in the "head" part
See https://squidfunk.github.io/mkdocs-material/customization/#overriding-partials for more details.

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming your are using MkDocs Material** as your Theme, inside your **mkdocs.yml** you can add Entries to the `extra_javascript` List.

*mkdocs.yml*:

```yaml
site_name: "..."
theme: "..."
# ...
extra_javascript:
  - https://cdn.someCdn.someLibrary.js # Online Resource
  - js/ourJsFile.js # Path relative to "docs" Directory
# Works the same way for CSS!
extra_css:
  - css/someCSS.css # Again, relative to the "docs" Directory
```

For reference: https://squidfunk.github.io/mkdocs-material/customization/#adding-assets

Comment: I tried this - it is being added to the footer, not the header.

Answer (score 0):

The `extrahead` placeholder, which should be present in all themes, allows additions to be made to the `<head>`.

You need to specify a `custom_dir` in the YAML file and in this directory have a `main.html` with an `extrahead` block.

See:

https://www.mkdocs.org/user-guide/customizing-your-theme/#using-the-theme_dir

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
 <script src="https://file.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    {{ content }}
  </body>
</html>
```